# Des / de bien cruelles

Tags: grammaire

Bonjour,

Dans *Voyage au bout de la nuit* :

> Pour que dans le cerveau d’un couillon, la pensée fasse un tour, il
> faut qu’il lui arrive beaucoup de choses et **des** bien cruelles.

Est-ce correct d'écrire ***des*** *bien cruelles*, ou la grammaire aurait attendu ***de** bien cruelles* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tout d'abord on peut juste considérer que ce « des » est la reprise du déterminant indéfini de la proposition précédente qui serait « il lui arrive des choses » si la proposition était écrite sans l'adverbe « beaucoup ».

Ensuite, la reprise se faisant avec l'ajout d'un adjectif antéposé on pourrait appliquer l'usage qui dit que l'article indéfini pluriel est généralement réduit à « de », ce qui n'est qu'un usage (certains disent de la langue soignée) et pas une règle. Il serait en effet correct d'écrire : « ... il faut qu’il lui arrive beaucoup de choses et de bien cruelles. »

Mais, et c'est mon hypothèse, on peut aussi considérer que dans cette proposition **le mot « choses » est implicite** : « ... il faut qu’il lui arrive beaucoup de choses et des [choses] bien cruelles ». Auquel cas seul « des » est possible. À mon avis, ce procédé permet d'insister sur le fait qu'il s'agit de la totalité des choses qu'il lui arrive, en quelque sorte « des » définis les choses dont il est question.

On trouve dans *Le bon usage* de nombreux exemples d'emploi de *des* devant des groupes pluriels adjectif + nom.<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Grevisse §330, 10<sup>e</sup> édition : *J'ai reçu des belles fleurs* (Maurice Donnay) — *Des petits cris de rats* (Albert Camus) —

Avec le nom implicite : *Des petits carrés de lumière s'allumaient. Il y en avait des blancs, des jaunes et des rouges* (Jean Sarment) — *Ils ont aussi des « Entreprises générales d'Incendies ». Des grandes, et de plus petites*. (remarquez le traitement différent des deux syntagmes.</sup>

Comment: Merci beaucoup. J'avais appris qu'on devrait écrire "de" devant des groupes pluriels adjectif + nom. Je viens de trouver chez La Rochefoucauld : "... ont fait entreprendre de grandes choses." Je suppose donc que l'emploi de/des dans ces cas est facultatif.

Comment: @ovide Tout à fait facultatif. Je sais que les pages de google books ne sont pas visibles dans tous les pays. Mais si tu peux voir [ces pages 819-820](https://books.google.fr/books?id=SX0wDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA820&lpg=PA820&dq=%22DES+vieilles+chansons+(NERVAL,+filles+du+Feu.+Sylvie,+XI)%22&source=bl&ots=U4ZDmPOZwY&sig=ACfU3U3N-KfGUzl8juZ_dqduByTH_CU3SA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDs6r05YT1AhWiy4UKHX8gBfwQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22DES%20vieilles%20chansons%20(NERVAL%2C%20filles%20du%20Feu.%20Sylvie%2C%20XI)%22&f=false) lis le § 584 et l'historique.

Comment: Merci encore, None !

Comment: @ovide De rien ! Mme de Sévigné *sous des belles et douces apparences* un des nombreux exemples du *Bon Usage*.